# Did Heimlich maneuvre posters become mandatory in New York shortly after that technique was performed on mayor Ed Koch in 1981?

Tags: united-states, history

The New York Times reports in its [obituary](https://www.nytimes.com/2013/02/02/nyregion/memories-of-koch-by-times-reporters-who-covered-him.html) on former New York mayor [Ed Koch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Koch), that posters on the [Heimlich maneuvre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdominal_thrusts) became mandatory in New York restaurants when the mayor got rescued by it:

> If you have ever wondered why restaurants in this city, from the greasiest spoons to the most haute of cuisines, must display Heimlich maneuver posters, it is because a choking Mr. Koch was rescued by that technique at a Chinatown restaurant in the summer of 1981. The next thing you knew, he invited Dr. Henry J. Heimlich to City Hall’s Blue Room, allowing himself to be used as a guinea pig while the doctor demonstrated his maneuver for reporters. In short order, the posters became mandatory.

But according to the [Wall Street Journal](https://www.wsj.com/articles/new-york-city-restaurant-choking-posters-get-an-alternative-makeover-1406507599), such a law was signed by Ed Koch three years earlier. The respective law might be [§17-172](https://law.justia.com/codes/new-york/2006/new-york-city-administrative-code-new/adc017-172_17-172.html). I cannot find a year when it was passed.

By this [NYT article from 1981](https://www.nytimes.com/1981/08/07/nyregion/mayor-relives-a-fright-to-show-choking-cure.html), the maneuvre was indeed performed on Koch that year, and he invited Dr. Heimlich to the *Blue Room*.

Although the NYT seems to insinuate some relationship between the maneuvre being performed on Koch and the law being passed, I imagine such a relationship may be difficult to establish, since Koch's motivation and his specific influence on passing the law may be difficult to reconstruct. Thus I would like to limit the question on the mere temporal succession on both events: Was such a law regarding mandatory posters passed shortly after the maneuvre was performed on Koch? The claim is absent in Koch's English Wikipedia article, but appears in its German version. I am skeptical about the claim, but hesitant to change the German article against the authority of the NYT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The New York Times obituary is incorrect. The law was passed in 1978.

I found the law in a 1986 publication of New York City laws ([link](https://www.google.com/books/edition/New_York_City_Charter_and_Administrative/nyhPAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22Dislodging+food+from+person+choking%3B+poster%22&dq=%22Dislodging+food+from+person+choking%3B+poster%22&printsec=frontcover)). That in itself isn't helpful. However, I also noticed the publication had an annotation immediately after each law that included when that particular law was added. [Searching for the next law in the sequence](https://www.google.com/search?q=17-173+%22dangers+of+consuming+alcoholic+beverages%22%3B+new+york&biw=1536&bih=775&tbm=bks&ei=a6LOYK7vGta6tAbr9rGYDA&oq=17-173+%22dangers+of+consuming+alcoholic+beverages%22%3B+new+york) (to get around the fact that I can only see a snippet of the search result) shows that the law was added in 1978:
"DERIVATION Formerly § 568-1.0 added LL 43/1978 § 1."

You can read a portion of that in this image (the trimmed text on the very top; the law we are interested in is [§ 17-172](https://www.google.com/books/edition/New_York_City_Charter_and_Administrative/nyhPAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22Dislodging+food+from+person+choking%3B+poster%22&dq=%22Dislodging+food+from+person+choking%3B+poster%22&printsec=frontcover)):

[image]

A 1989 issue of Spy magazine [says](https://books.google.com/books?id=dn1qTsnNKAwC&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=%22local+law+43%22+%22heimlich#v=onepage&q=%22local%20law%2043%22%20%22heimlich) that the law was passed in December 21, 1978 as Local Law 43, though I don't know how trustworthy that is. An [NYC site](https://www1.nyc.gov/assets/doh/downloads/pdf/rii/fpc-manual.pdf) does include "City Council Local Law 43" on the poster. LL 43 presumably also refers to "Local Law 43."